# Give RPM macro an argument with spaces

Tags: macros, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Example RPM macro:

```
%define hello() \
    printf 'hello, %{1}.\\n';
```

I would like to be able to give it macros with spaces in it, as in:

```
%{hello "Dak Tyson"}

->

printf 'hello, Dak Tyson.\n'
```

However, it keeps doing this:

```
%{hello "Dak Tyson"}

->

printf 'hello, "Dak.\n'
```

In other words, it doesn't interpret the double quotes, but uses them as-is.

Single quotes don't work either:

```
%{hello 'Dak Tyson'}

->

printf 'hello, 'Dak\.\n'
```

Nor backslashes:

```
%{hello Dak\ Tyson}

->

printf 'hello, Dak\.\n'
```

Nor braces:

```
%{hello {Dak Tyson}}

->

printf 'hello, {Dak.\n'
```

*Is there any way to give an RPM macro arguments with spaces?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I trawled through the [RPM API C code](http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/) having to do with [macro expansion](http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/macro_8c-source.html#l01218). I found a loop in there which uses spaces to parse out the arguments and (I think) there is no way around this loop. I don't think you can give arguments with spaces.

I did find that macro arguments are safe, though.

My `.rpmmacros` file:

```
%hello() '%{1}'
%name Dak Tyson
```

With the above macros defined, This command:

```
rpm --eval '%{hello %{name}}'
```

yields:

```
'Dak Tyson'
```

So that if I really needed spaces in my macros definitions, I can define them as macros first.

I also found, incidentally, that nested parameterized macros don't work.

This command:

```
rpm --eval '%{hello %{hello name}}'
```

yields:

```
error: Unterminated {: {hello
  2<     (empty)
  1<   (empty)
  0< '
'
```

Comment: IJWTS thanks for reading through the RPM source code for this, so that I didn't have to.